# Assembly Ubuntu x86 segmentation fault

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, assembly, x86

I've got the following assembly piece of code:

```
section .text
  global _start
    _start:
      ; Store the argument string on stack
      xor  eax, eax 
      push eax          ; Use 0 to terminate the string
      push "bash"
      mov al, 0x2f      ; Set "/" to the least significant byte of eax
      push eax          ; Add "/" onto the stack
      push "/bin"
      mov  ebx, esp     ; Get the string address

      ; Construct the argument array argv[]
      xor eax, eax      ; eax = 0x00000000
      push eax          ; argv[1] = 0
      push ebx          ; argv[0] points "/bin/bash"
      mov  ecx, esp     ; Get the address of argv[]
   
      ; For environment variable 
      xor  edx, edx     ; No env variables 

      ; Invoke execve()
      mov   al, 0x0b    ; eax = 0x0000000b
      int 0x80
```

It's supposed to call bash shell but it gives a segmentation fault after compiling to object code and linking to generate binary.
OS Ubuntu x86. Thanks in advance!

Adding extra shashes is forbidden to complete this task.

Comment: You forgot to show how you compile (actually assemble) and link, also did not provide info from debugger to see where the crash is, or output of strace to see what syscall you invoked. Chances are you produced a 64 bit binary instead of 32.

Comment: The `push eax` would stop it from assembling as 64-bit, unless there's a `bits 32` that's not shown.  But yes, a better question would show build commands and debugger output, at least showing the faulting instruction.  (Or I guess that would be something after `int 0x80`.  So better, `strace ./a.out` output to see what args actually got passed to `execve` and why it failed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the `mov al, 0x2f; push eax` which will push 4 bytes not 1.
Try:

```
  push "h"
  push "/bas"
  push "/bin"
  mov  ebx, esp     ; Get the string address
```

Also make sure you create 32 bit binary.